# webpack depending on sub-project webpack result

Tags: webpack

So I have this project that is using webpack+babel+react loader. It has a local dependency to another project which also uses webpack+babel loader.

Is it possible to configure webpack to have its dependency run webpack and only then run its own considering the result of the dependency?

Comment: sounds like something that should use gulp with webpack.  perhaps run tasks in series?

Answer (score -1):

You should use multiple entry point

```
{
    entry: {
        a: "./a",
        b: "./b",
        c: ["./c", "./d"]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "[name].entry.js"
    }
}
```

Each of these entry points could be your different js from different projects.
You can define split points in your code base. Webpack will resolve dependencies, output files and runtime stuff.